# Formal title/honorific for a lawyer

Tags: writing-style, formality, honorifics, professions, forms-of-address

Let's say there is a lawyer named Sue Smith.

She could be referred to as Ms. Smith, but is there a different formal prepended honorific specific to lawyers?

Particularly when addressing one directly.

Comment: That's not a prefix: in fact, it’s a ***non***prefix.  An ***un**lawyer* has had a prefix ***re**applied* to her. You just are looking for her personal or professional title used in courteous address, like Doctor Smith has a title or Mister Rogers has a title or Captain Kirk or President Lincoln. Let's call them honorifics for now. But titles used in direct address are not always the same ones used in indirect reference. This is why [you can call the cook *Cook* but you cannot call the butler *Butler*](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/548977). :)

Comment: @tchrist Oh thank you! I never knew what those were called, I just remembered seeing them mislabeled as "prefix" on forms and stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never heard of a prefix (assuming you mean *prepended honorific*) used for lawyers the way Doctor or Professor are used. But it is common for lawyers in the US to use the postpended honorific "Esquire" (as "Esq.") when writing to or about each other. No one ever refers to themselves as Esq, only to others. It's not a legal designation -- anyone can call anyone, or themselves, Esq.

So you'll see letters captioned or addressed to "John Smith Esq." as a courtesy between lawyers, but you won't see letters signed "John Smith Esq."

Here's an [article](https://www.differencebetween.com/difference-between-esquire-and-vs-attorney/) that goes into it a bit.

Comment: Agreed.  Sue Smith may hold the degree "J.D."  (Doctor of Law), but she is not referred to as "Dr Sue Smith" because of that.  She would perhaps identify herself in writing as  "Sue Smith, J.D."

Comment: It should be emphasised that *Esq.* is used only in writing, and clarified that it is normally used only the first time a name appears within a document. A letter may thus be addressed to 'Sue Smith, Esq.', but the salutation would be 'Dear Ms. Smith'. The short answer to the OP's question is, however, **no**; in this respect English is different from, say, French. Incidentally, shouldn't there be a comma between the surname and *Esq.*?